# How can I call code that uses `Start-ThreadJob` from the PowerShell SDK?

Tags: .net, powershell, msbuild, csproj

I have an app that is using the [PowerShell SDK](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/depending-on-the-right-powershell-nuget-package-in-your-net-project/) to execute PowerShell code in the background.

However, that code depends on `Start-Job`, and the PowerShell script is throwing an exception when I run it in my app:

```cs
_powerShellInstance.AddScript("DoSomethingWithStartJob").Invoke();
```

> The pwsh executable cannot be found at "C:\Users\ben\Projects\Foo\Foo (Package)\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\Foo\runtimes\win\lib\net8.0\pwsh.exe".
> Note that 'Start-Job' is not supported by design in scenarios where PowerShell is being hosted in other applications. Instead, usage of the 'ThreadJob' module is recommended in such scenarios.

I want to port to use `Start-ThreadJob` like the error says, but I don't know how! How can I get my **C# app** to install the **ThreadJob** module into my **PowerShell SDK** installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any PS module available in PSGallery. To support `ThreadJob` specifically:

1. Added `ThreadJob`'s PSGallery nuget package to our feed
2. Created a custom build step to manually copy the `ThreadJob` module contents to our output dir.

##### Adding ThreadJob to the feed

In your `nuget.config` ([example nuget.config](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/b2ba58442353e740d5e2a45a804da6cfef6c21a3/src/Modules/nuget.config#L5C1-L6C1)):

```xml
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <!-- ... -->
    <add key="PSGallery" value="https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
```

In your `csproj` ([example csproj](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/b2ba58442353e740d5e2a45a804da6cfef6c21a3/src/Modules/PSGalleryModules.csproj#L19); in our case, we were deploying a WinUI project so we edited the package `wapproj` instead):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- ... -->
  <PackageReference Include="ThreadJob" Version="2.0.3">
    <!-- Necessary for the next step: -->
    <GeneratePathProperty>True</GeneratePathProperty>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

This adds the pacakge to your project.

In our case, we had a custom NuGet feed in ADO, so we just added `ThreadJob` to its cache.

##### Create custom build step

In the same `csproj`/`wapproj` that references the `ThreadJob` package:

```
  <Target Name="CopyThreadJob" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="ThreadJob module files: @(ThreadJobFiles)" Importance="high"></Message>
    <Message Text="Deploying ThreadJob module to: $(OutDir)AppX\Foo\runtimes\win\lib\net8.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.ThreadJob\" Importance="high"></Message>
      <!-- If you want other targets, like UNIX, you'll need to copy to those Modules\ directories, too -->
      <!-- Remember, the subdir in Modules needs to exactly match the name of the .psd1 -->
      <Copy SourceFiles="@(ThreadJobFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\AppX\Foo\runtimes\win\lib\net8.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.ThreadJob\" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  </Target>
```

---

Now your code can invoke `Start-ThredJob`!

```
_powerShellInstance.AddScript("Start-ThreadJob").Invoke();
```